# Rails, uninitialized constant Getting Started with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through the RailsGuide (Section 5.6) and hit the following error:

NameError in ArticlesController#create
uninitialized constant Active_Record

I suspect this a pluralization issue. I have read through the documentation on pluralization of controllers, however, I still can't nail down where the error is occurring, any help would be much appreciated.

```html
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create

  @article = Article.new(params[:article])


  @article.save
  redirect_to @article

  end



end
```

```html
class CreateArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   resources :articles

   root 'welcome#index'


end
```

```html
class Article < Active_Record::base


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `class Article < Active_Record::base` to `class Article < ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 1):

It's not Active_Record it's ActiveRecord which is why you're getting the initialized constant error.

Comment: Yeah, to clarify Active_Record::Base -> ActiveRecord::Base